# LinkedList never terminates input taking in Java

Tags: java, input

I am making a linked list program in Java. However when I invoke the method get_values(); it keeps asking for input. I can't seem to stop it. Since I can't figure out the problem in the code, I am pasting the whole program code here.

```
import java.io.*; //Importing Java Input-Output Library
class Node
{
    int x;
    Node next; //Initializing Node data type named next
    Node() //method to set all values to 0
    {
        x=0;
        next=null;
    }

    void get_data(int a) //get data from user
    {
        x=a;
    }

    int put_data() // print returned values
    {
        return x;
    }
}

class List
{
    Node start; //Another node (user created variable)
    List()
    {
        start=null;
    }

    void Add_Node(int a) // Add or Creating new nodes and linking them
    {
        Node n=new Node();
        n.get_data(a);
        if(start==null)
        {
            start=n;
        }
        else if(start!=null)
        {
            for(Node temp=start, prev=start; temp!=null; prev=temp, temp=temp.next) //sorting
            {
                if(temp.x>n.x && temp==start)
                {
                    n.next=temp;
                    start=n;
                }
                else if(temp.x<n.x && temp.next==null)
                {
                    temp.next=n;
                }
                else if(temp.x>n.x && prev.x<n.x)
                {
                    n.next=temp;
                    prev.next=n;
                }
                }
            }
        }
    void traverse() //printing traversed values
    {
        for(Node temp=start; temp!=null; temp=temp.next)
        {
            System.out.print(temp.put_data()+"  ");
        }
    }
    void extraction(int b) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader ist=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ist);
        int a;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {   
            System.out.println("Enter the value for node "+i+":");
            a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
            Add_Node(a);
        }
        traverse();
        Node store_new=null;
        boolean match_check=false;
        for(Node temp=start, prev=start; temp!=null; prev=temp, temp=temp.next)
        {
            if(temp.x==b && temp!=null)
            {
                match_check=true;
                store_new=temp;
                break;
            }
            else if(temp.x!=b)
            {
                //match_check=false;
            }
        }
        if(match_check==true)
        {
            System.out.println("Value found. The value address is: "+store_new+" and the value stored in it is: "+store_new.x);
        }
        else if(match_check==false)
        {
            System.out.println("Value not found in the list, please enter a value which exists in the list.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public class LinkedList //main class
{
    static void get_values() throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader ist=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ist);
        List l=new List();
        int a;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {   
            System.out.println("Enter the value for node "+i+":");
            a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
            l.Add_Node(a);
        }
        l.traverse();
    }
    static void extract() throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader ist=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ist);
        List l=new List();
        int b;
        System.out.println("Enter the value for extraction: ");
        b=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        l.extraction(b);
    }
    static void sublist()
    {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader ist=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ist);
        List l = new List();
        int input;
        boolean Menu_check=false;
        System.out.println("Enter a the corresponding number to select the menu and then press enter");
        System.out.println("1. Enter values and traverse them");
        System.out.println("2. Enter a value and find it in the list");
        System.out.println("3. Enter a range to be extracted from the list");
        System.out.println("4. Exit?");
        input=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if(input<5 && input>0)
        {
            Menu_check=true;
        }
        while(Menu_check=true)
        {
            switch(input)
            {
                case 1: get_values();
                        break;
                case 2: extract();
                        break;
                case 3: sublist();
                        break;
                case 4: System.out.println("Goodbye");
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Can someone please go over my code and help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. compare primitives with == in java
2. There is a logical fail. I think you want ask the user again for input still the input is 4 and only do something if the input is smaller than 5 and greater than 0.

Change your main to this:

```
    InputStreamReader ist=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ist);
    List l = new List();
    int input;

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a the corresponding number to select the menu and then press enter");
        System.out.println("1. Enter values and traverse them");
        System.out.println("2. Enter a value and find it in the list");
        System.out.println("3. Enter a range to be extracted from the list");
        System.out.println("4. Exit?");
        input=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        if(input<5 && input>0)
        {
            switch(input)
            {
                case 1: get_values();
                        break;
                case 2: extract();
                        break;
                case 3: sublist();
                        break;
                case 4: System.out.println("Goodbye");
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also remove case 4 and do `while(input != 4)` instead of `while(true)`. If you do it like this you habe to initialize `input` with something that is not equal to 4.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Menu_check=true` for your break condition. In Java (and most if not all other languages), one `=` is setting the variable while `==` is for comparison.

What you're doing is setting `Menu_check` to true every time, thus your loop will continue indefinitely. What you want is `Menu_check==true`.

However, you if really want an interactive console, you should get rid of your `Menu_check` boolean and just do a while loop like thus:

```
while(true)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a the corresponding number to select the menu and then press enter");
    System.out.println("1. Enter values and traverse them");
    System.out.println("2. Enter a value and find it in the list");
    System.out.println("3. Enter a range to be extracted from the list");
    System.out.println("4. Exit?");

    input=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if(input>5 || input<0)
    {
        break;
    }

    switch(input)
    {
        case 1: get_values();
                break;
        case 2: extract();
                break;
        case 3: sublist();
                break;
        case 4: System.out.println("Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since technically, Visual Basic is a (terrible) language, it is only most languages ;)

Comment: Thats is not the problem. Even if he do `Menu_check==true` it will still cause a endless loop because he never set it to false again.

Comment: yeah, there's a bunch of problems wrong with his code, made an updated suggestion to just maintain an infinite loop instead of this `Menu_check` boolean

Answer (score 0):

corrections

1.Keep true == Menu_check.

2.keep this snippet inside while before switch

```
input=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if(input<5 && input>0)
        {
            Menu_check=true;
        }else
        {
            Menu_check=false;
        }
```

to make it interactive menu